# How to get all months as a date from a start & end date in DAX

Tags: date, dax, ssas, calculated-columns

im working on a calculated column in a SSAS model.
My Idea is to generate every month as date ( f.e 2021-01-01) based on a start and end date, who are also columns of that entry. Basically i wanna duplicate every entries with the month column for further calculations

when i have startdate 2021-04-28 and enddate  2022-02-28
i want to have 2021-04-01 , 2021-05-01 etc... till 2022-02-01

how do i write this in DAX?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Calendar = 
VAR start_date = DATE( 2021, 4, 28 )
VAR end_date = DATE( 2022, 2, 28 )
VAR start_date_first = DATE( YEAR( start_date ), MONTH( start_date ), 1 )
VAR end_date_eom = EOMONTH( end_date, 0 )
VAR result = 
    FILTER(
        CALENDAR( start_date_first, end_date_eom ),
        DAY( [Date] ) = 1
    )
RETURN
    result
```

Comment: i think i have to apolosied to forget to mention, that startdate and enddate are also colunms and i want to have the months for every entry based  on thier date column. basically i want to duplicate my entires with the calcluated coulmn

Comment: I assumed that those dates come from columns but I also assumed that you would adjust the code a bit. Use the min and max instead of hardcoded dates. I don't understand the second part. It looks like you want a cross join of your data with a range of dates (from start to end date), don't you? Provide sample data and expected output, please.